# unrecognized arguments: True

Tags: python, argparse

Code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Build dataset')
    parser.add_argument('--do_plot', action="store_true",
                        help='Plot the images')
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

Error:

```
$ python make_dataset.py --do_plot True
usage: make_dataset.py [-h] [--do_plot]           
make_dataset.py: error: unrecognized arguments: True
```

Answer (score 8):

As you've configured it, the `--do_plot` option does not take any arguments. A `store_true` argument in `argparse` indicates that the very presence of the option will automatically store `True` in the corresponding variable.

So, to prevent your problem, just stop passing `True` to `--do_plot`.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to indicate True as far as I can tell, by just including `--do_plot`, it is telling it that you wanted to do plot. And plus, you did not configure it to take any arguments.

In the following line of the source code:

```
if args.do_plot:
```

If you actually included `--do_plot` in the command lines, it will be evaluated as True, if not, it will be evaluated as False.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the specification here:

```
parser.add_argument('--do_plot', action="store_true",
                    help='Plot ...')
```

You've declared **do_plot** as an option without an argument; the **True** afterward has no purpose in your argument protocol.  This is an option that's off by omission, on when present.

Answer (score -1):

Just one of reason (which I faced) and hope my hypothesis helps your problem is that on Ubuntu (on Windows, IDK but it's fine),

When you imported a function from a `.py` file (let say `A.py`) which having args (people create `__main__` to test a feature function, let call `A` function ). The `.py` importing/using `A` could be confusedly parsing arguments because `A.py` also parse arguments and so on.

So, you could solve by refactoring, or just (temporarily) comment out them to run first.